# Oracle tnsping ok, spring JdbcTemplate TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, spring-mvc

Estou enfrentando um problema, espero que possam me ajudar,
Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web rodando sobre tomcat utilizando Spring-mvc e acesso a dados com JdbcTemplate, o banco de dados é o Oracle 11g. 
Dentro deste cenário como de prache, tenho dois ambientes, no ambiente de desenvolvimento tudo funciona perfeitamente, acesso a dados, páginas etc. No
ambiente de produção não consigo conectar no banco de forma alguma, testando pelas ferramentas externas (tnsping, PlSQL) conecta certinho, quando rodo 
o tomcat e tento acessar a pagina, tenho a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

)] with root cause
oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
       at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:399)

As configurações ed acesso a dados estão gravadas no context e no server.xml do tomcat, segue a listagem das configurações:

context.xml

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/OracleDB"
                global="jdbc/OracleDB"
                auth="Container"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

Server.xml dentro do nó GlobalNamingResources

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        global="jdbc/OracleDB" maxActive="100" maxIdle="20" maxWait="10000"
        minIdle="5" name="jdbc/OracleDB" password="SGC" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@NB-ATROMBETONE:1521:xe" username="SGC" />
```

As duas configurações citadas acima são do ambiente de desenv, no ambiente de produção altero apenas os atributos, url, username e password do resource.

Já verifique regras de firewall, bloqueio de portas, antivírus, mas nada resolveu.
Alguém tem alguma sugestão ou passou por isso?

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: a base de dados está catalogada no TNSNames do oracle na maquina onde ocorreu o deploy?

Comment: Olá amigo, obrigado pela iteração, respondendo sua questão, está sim, no mesmo pc consigo testar a conexão pelo tnsping e pelo PLSql, ambos funcionam normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

problema resolvido. Com auxilio de um profissional da aréa de banco de dados, encontramos na documentação do Oracle (vide link: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/jdbcthin.htm#i1004498) a solução.

Resolução: Executar o TNSPing com o SID desejado.
Após obter a resposta positiva do teste, pegue o bloco do TNSNAMES que foi utilizado para resolver o apelido. vide imagem:

[image: Print do retorno do tnsping]

Certo, agora que já possui o retorno, altere a string de conexão removendo toda a parte final a partir do hostname do servidor, em seguida adicione o bloco que está em destaque na imagem.

Antes-> `jdbc:oracle:thin:@NB-ATROMBETONE:1521:xe`

Depois-> `jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = NB-ATROMBETONE)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))`

Obrigado a todos.